# Plotting Regression results from lme4 in R using Lattice (or something else)

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4

I have fit a regression using lme4 thanks to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539/linear-regression-and-group-by-in-r). Now that I have a regression fit for each state I'd like to use lattice to plot QQ plots for each state. I would also like to plot error plots for each state in a lattice format. How do I make a lattice plot using the results of a lme4 regression?

Below is a simple sample (yeah, I like a good alliteration) using two states. I would like to make a two panel lattice made from the object fits.

```
library(lme4)
d <- data.frame(state=rep(c('NY', 'CA'), c(10, 10)), year=rep(1:10, 2), response=c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10)))
fits <- lmList(response ~ year | state, data=d)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `lmList`, I'd recommend the more general plyr package.

```
library(plyr)

d <- data.frame(
 state = rep(c('NY', 'CA'), c(10, 10)), 
 year = rep(1:10, 2), 
 response = c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
)

# Create a list of models
# dlply = data frame -> list
models <- dlply(d, ~ state, function(df) { 
  lm(response ~ year, data = df)
})

# Extract the coefficients in a useful form
# ldply = list -> data frame
ldply(models, coef)

# We can get the predictions in a similar way, but we need
# to cast to a data frame so the numbers come out as rows,
# not columns.
predictions <- ldply(models, as.data.frame(predict))
```

`predictions` is a regular R data frame and so is easy to plot.

Comment: well you just sold me on learning the plyr package. :) I had gone with lme4 because I could grok what it was doing easier than what plyr does. Now I see an advantage to plyr. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a heck of a time joining my predicted values back to the original data set. In the example above NY is first in the input data.frame and CA is first in the output.The field [year] is not retained in the data.frame [predictions]. This is probably obvious, but how do I join these back?

Comment: instead of `as.data.frame(predict)`, use something like

    function(model) {
      transform(d, pred = predict(model))
    }

Comment: I've gotten so much good use out of this method this week. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you can get this into lattice easily.  What you have in `fits` is a an S4 object containing a .Data slot with a list of *standard* `lm` objects:

```
R> class(fits)
[1] "lmList"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lme4"
R> class(fits@.Data)
[1] "list"
R> class(fits@.Data[[1]])
[1] "lm"
R> op <- par(mfrow=c(2,4))
R> invisible(lapply(fits@.Data, plot))
```

This last plot simply plots you the standard 2x2 plot for `lm` objects twice, once for each element of the list of fitted objects.  Use the `which` argument to `plot` to select subsets of these  or for other regression diagnostics.

If you actually want `lattice` plots of predicted vs actual, you may have to program this.

Answer (score -1):

I've had some trouble with lme4::lmList. For example, summary doesn't seem to work. So you might run into some problems because of that.

So even though I use lmer, instead of lme, I've been explicitly calling nlme::lmList instead. Then summary etc. will work.