# How to overlay a line for an lm object on a ggplot2 scatterplot

Tags: graphics, r, ggplot2

I have some data,

```
calvarbyruno.1<-structure(list(Nominal = c(1, 3, 6, 10, 30, 50, 150, 250), Run = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    PAR = c(1.25000000000000e-05, 0.000960333333333333, 0.00205833333333334, 
    0.00423333333333333, 0.0322333333333334, 0.614433333333334, 
    1.24333333333333, 1.86333333333333), PredLin = c(-0.0119152187070942, 
    0.00375925114245899, 0.0272709559167888, 0.0586198956158952, 
    0.215364594111427, 0.372109292606959, 1.15583278508462, 1.93955627756228
    ), PredQuad = c(-0.0615895732702735, -0.0501563307416599, 
    -0.0330831368244257, -0.0104619953693943, 0.100190275883806, 
    0.20675348710041, 0.6782336426345, 1.04748729725370)), .Names = c("Nominal", 
"Run", "PAR", "PredLin", "PredQuad"), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
calweight <- -2
```

for which I've created both a linear and a quadratic lm model

```
callin.1<-lm(PAR~Nominal,data=calvarbyruno.1,weight=Nominal^calweight)
calquad.1<-lm(PAR~Nominal+I(Nominal^2),data=calvarbyruno.1,weight=Nominal^calweight)
```

I can then plot my data values using ggplot2

```
qplot(PAR,Nominal,data=calvarbyruno.1)
```

But can't work out how to overlay a line representing the two lm objects... Any ideas ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easiest option is to use geom_smooth() and let ggplot2 fit the model for you.

```
ggplot(calvarbyruno.1, aes(y = PAR, x = Nominal, weight=Nominal^calweight)) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), colour = "red") + 
    geom_point() + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image: Illustration using geom_smooth]

Or you can create a new dataset with the predicted values.

```
newdata <- data.frame(Nominal = pretty(calvarbyruno.1$Nominal, 100))
newdata$Linear <- predict(callin.1, newdata = newdata)
newdata$Quadratic <- predict(calquad.1, newdata = newdata)
require(reshape2)
newdata <- melt(newdata, id.vars = "Nominal", variable.name = "Model")
ggplot(calvarbyruno.1, aes(x = PAR, y = Nominal, weight=Nominal^calweight)) + 
    geom_line(data = newdata, aes(x = value, colour = Model)) + 
    geom_point()
```

Comment: Thierry, do you mind posting an image of the results?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Earlier I asked a related question and Hadley had [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297698/plotting-regression-results-from-lme4-in-r-using-lattice-or-something-else/1299539#1299539).  Using the predict function from that post you can add two columns to your data. One for each model:

```
calvarbyruno.1$calQuad <- predict(calquad.1)
calvarbyruno.1$callin <- predict(callin.1)
```

Then it's a matter of plotting the point and adding each model in as a line:

```
ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=calvarbyruno.1, aes(PAR, Nominal), colour="green") + 
geom_line(data=calvarbyruno.1, aes(calQuad, Nominal), colour="red" ) + 
geom_line(data=calvarbyruno.1, aes(callin, Nominal), colour="blue" ) + 
opts(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

And that results in this nice picture (yeah the colors could use some work):

[image]
<sub>(source: [cerebralmastication.com](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/ggplot2.png))</sub>