# ggplot2: Plotting regression lines with different intercepts but with same slope

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I want to plot regression lines with different intercepts but with the same slope.

With the following `ggplot2` code, I can plot regression lines with different intercepts and different slopes. But could not figured out how to draw regression lines with different different intercepts but the same slopes.

```
library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(data=df3, mapping=aes(x=Income, y=Consumption, color=Gender)) + geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(data=df3, method = "lm", se=FALSE, mapping=aes(x=Income, y=Consumption))

Consumption <- c(51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 57, 55, 56, 58, 59, 62, 63)
Gender <- gl(n = 2, k = 6, length = 2*6, labels = c("Male", "Female"), ordered = FALSE)
Income <- rep(x=c(80, 90, 100), each=2)
df3 <- data.frame(Consumption, Gender, Income)
df3

# Regression with same slope but different intercepts for each Gender
fm1 <- lm(formula=Consumption~Gender+Income, data=df3)
summary(fm1)

Call:
lm(formula = Consumption ~ Gender + Income, data = df3)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.8333 -0.8333  0.1667  0.1667  1.1667 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  26.83333    2.54557   10.54 2.30e-06 ***
GenderFemale  5.00000    0.45812   10.91 1.72e-06 ***
Income        0.30000    0.02805   10.69 2.04e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7935 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9629,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9546 
F-statistic: 116.7 on 2 and 9 DF,  p-value: 3.657e-07
```

Comment: Why don't you add a `geom_line` with the results from `lm`, i.e. do the calculation outside of ggplot? Technically as you see in your model there is not two different intercepts but an extra offset to the dummy `GenderFemale`

Comment: Might be a statistical issue. What your ggplot code does by using color=Gender is to create a linear regression model for each gender. So, the model will determine if they have the same slope and/or the same intercept. If it happens to actually have same slope and different intercepts be sure that it will be plotted. Why do you want to force the same slope for both genders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you calculate the regression outside of ggplot with the results from `lm`:

```
# Regression with same slope but different intercepts for each Gender
fm1 <- lm(formula=Consumption~Gender+Income, data=df3)
df3 = cbind(df3, pred = predict(fm1))

ggplot(data=df3, mapping=aes(x=Income, y=Consumption, color=Gender)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line(mapping=aes(y=pred))
```

Produces same slope and different intercepts: 
[image]

Technically as you see in your model there is not two different intercepts but an extra offset to the dummy variable `GenderFemale`.

Edit: included `predict` to simplify, thanks to @aosmith for suggesting.

Comment: You could simplify this a bit by using `predict` with your `lm1` object, either with a new dataset [as shown here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-December/343458.html) or by adding the predictions directly to the original dataset for plotting [like in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1477938/2461552)

Comment: what is the utility in running `fm1s <- summary(fm1)` in your above example?

Comment: @bpace thanks for pointing out, there was no use of this after I implemented the change suggested by aosmith.