# stat_smooth with different colors using geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I want to plot two numeric variables against each other in a scatterplot and the points should have different colors for each category of another binary variable. I also want to have regression lines.
This is my straight forward code:

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(cats, aes(Bwt, Hwt, color = Sex)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm")
```

However these are lines from two separate regressions.
I want to have the regression lines from the following regression:

```
lm(Hwt ~ Bwt + Sex, data = cats)
```

I've tried the following, but this doesn't work:

```
ggplot(cats, aes(Bwt, Hwt, color = Sex)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = Hwt ~ Bwt + Sex)
```

Is there an easy (!) way to achieve this?
It would be no problem for me to write a more complex code but that's not what I'm searching for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903606/ggplot2-plotting-regression-lines-with-different-intercepts-but-with-same-slope

Comment: You can at least use the same approach as the link I provided. I don't know if there is an easier way.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a good idea. I've found that one, that's quite good: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mosaic/versions/1.8.3/topics/plotModel But I thought that there has to be an easier way with `stat_smooth`.