# Returning a vector of attributes shared by a set of objects

Tags: r

I have a list of `lm` (linear model) objects.

How can I select a particular element (such as the intercept, rank, or residuals) from all the objects in a single call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the `plyr` package and then if my list of objects was called `modelOutput` and I want to get out all the predicted values I would do this:

```
modelPredictions <- ldply(modelOutput, as.data.frame(predict))
```

if I want all the coefficients I do this:

```
modelCoef <- ldply(modelOutput, as.data.frame(coef))
```

Hadley originally showed me how to do this [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539/linear-regression-and-group-by-in-r/1214432#1214432).

Answer (score 2):

First I'll generate some example data:

```
> set.seed(123)
> x <- 1:10
> a <- 3
> b <- 5
> fit <- c()
> for (i in 1:10) {
+   y <- a + b*x + rnorm(10,0,.3)
+   fit[[i]] <- lm(y ~ x)
+ }
```

Here's one option for grabbing the estimates from each fit:

```
> t(sapply(fit, function(x) coef(x)))
      (Intercept)        x
 [1,]    3.157640 4.975409
 [2,]    3.274724 4.961430
 [3,]    2.632744 5.043616
 [4,]    3.228908 4.975946
 [5,]    2.933742 5.011572
 [6,]    3.097926 4.994287
 [7,]    2.709796 5.059478
 [8,]    2.766553 5.022649
 [9,]    2.981451 5.020450
[10,]    3.238266 4.980520
```

As you mention, other quantities concerning the fit are available.  Above I only grabbed the coefficients with the `coef()` function.  Check out the following command for more:

```
names(summary(fit[[1]]))
```