# Make regressions and predictions for groups in R

Tags: list, r, time-series, regression, plyr

I have the following data.frame `d` from an experiment:

```
- Variable y (response, continuous)
- Factor f (500 levels)
- Time t (posixct)
```

In the last 8 years, y was measured roughly once a month (exact date in t) for each level of f. Sometimes there are 2 measures per month, sometimes a couple of month passed without any measures.

Sorry for not providing example data, but making up unregular time series goes beyond my R knowledge. ;)

I'd like to do the following with this data:

1. make a regression using the `loess()` function `(y ~ t)`, for each level of `f`
2. make a prediction of `y` for the first day of each month and each level of `f`

The first point I think I solved by using Hadleys answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539/linear-regression-and-group-by-in-r) question:

```
models <- dlply(d, "f", function(df) loess(y ~ as.numeric(t), data = df))
```

So, now I have a `models` (class `list`), with a model for each level of `f`.
I also created times for which I'd like to predict `y` for each level of `f` like this:

```
dates <- seq(min(t),max(t),"months")
```

But now I'm stuck on how to make predictions for each model. Something like this should work (pseudocode):

```
for each f in models
    p.f <- predict(models(f),dates)
    p.f.complete <- r.bind(p.f.comlete,p.f)
next f
```

As a result, I'd like to have this data.frame:

- y.predicted
- f
- t.predicted (= dates)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most complicated thing to do is make the function to `predict` and ussing `lapply`. Which is not very hard to do.

```
dates <- data.frame(t = dates)
y.predicted <- lapply(models, function (x) predict(x, newdata = dates))
```

if you want to rbind y.predicted just use

```
y.predicted <- do.call(rbind, y.predicted)
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works well! To make a data.frame out of the list, I just used `melt(y.predicted)`.

Answer (score 2):

*Edited*

The key is to use ldply() with predict().  Here is an example using dummy data:

```
library(plyr)
d <- data.frame(
        f = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=20),
        t = rep(1:20, 5),
        y = runif(100))

models <- dlply(d, "f", function(df) loess(y ~ as.numeric(t), data = df))
predict(models[[1]])

x <- ldply(models, predict)
colnames(x) <- c("f", 1:20)
x
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would take me almost were I'd like to be, however it doesn't include predictions on `dates`. That's why I rated lselzer answer as the correct one.