# Pooled estimates - regression model with broom and tidyverse

Tags: r, regression, spss, broom

I'm working with a team and some people are using SPSS to replace missing case (multiple imputation) and, then, analyze the data. When SPSS impute new values, it reports every dataset result and a pooled result, that is different than the mean of all results.

Now, I'm using R to work on this "multiple imputation dataset" created on SPSS.  I'm trying to obtain the *pooled estimates* from a regression in the same way SPSS reports. Grace to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539/linear-regression-and-group-by-in-r), I can use broom package to run several regression models and show each estimate. The problem: some statistics are way different. For example, t value are higher when using broom than what was reported by SPSS.
Please, take a look to this SPSS output.

[image]

In order to make this job easy, let's say I want to regress **price** on **stars** for each **group** and, after, display a row with **pooled estimates** (t test result and p-value).

code:

```
   library(broom)
    d <- data.frame(group=rep(1:5, each = 20),
                    price=rnorm(100,1000,10),
                    stars=rnorm(100,3,1))
    fitted_models <- d %>% 
      group_by(group) %>% 
      do(model = lm(price ~ stars, data = .))
    fitted_models %>% tidy(model)
    fitted_models %>% glance(model)
```

In case you want to better understand what SPSS is doing, please, check this real output. The pooled is not the mean of all results.
[image: pooled]

Please, feel free to say this question is irrelevant, but don't negative this post. Other people can have the same question and I provide all codes to you run again the analysis.

Thanks much

Comment: I think you have two questions that don't belong together.  The first is, "what is SPSS doing when it calculates "Pooled" results?"  That's a question for CrossValidated, not Stack Overflow.  The second question is "How can I do XYZ in R"?  That could be a question for SO, depending on exactly what XYZ turns out to be.

Comment: You are right, @CurtF. I merged both questions into just one and probably it was not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure hwat you mean by "pooled" estimates -- does that just mean you want to run the model without grouping?

If so, then this should do what you want.

```
d <- data.frame(group=rep(1:5, each = 20),
                price=rnorm(100,1000,10),
                stars=rnorm(100,3,1)
               )

fitted_models <- 
    d %>% 
        group_by(group) %>% 
        do(tidy(lm(data=., formula=price ~ stars))) %>%
        ungroup %>%
        mutate(group=group %>% as.character)


pooled_model <-
    d %>%
    do(tidy(lm(data=., formula=price ~ stars))) %>%
    mutate(group='pooled')

all_results <- bind_rows(fitted_models, pooled_model) %>% select(group, everything())

all_results
```

Comment: Thanks, @curt-f, but this script overestimate the statistic and the p.value. In the real dataset, each model has a "t statistic" like 9, but the pooled model has 42. I don't know how to fix that. Do you ? Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question with a formula or equation for "pooled estimate"?

Comment: Dear, @curt-f, I'll edit the question. But, unfortunately, I don´t know how SPSS arrives at this result.

Comment: I don't think you will get help with your R code until you can better specify what exactly you​ want it to do.

Comment: Ok, @curt-f, I'll edit again the initial text. Thanks.