# ANOVA on list of lmList linear regressions

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a list of linear regressions generated using `lmList` (from lme4), similar to what was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169672/8157810):

Now I want to compare these models using an ANOVA.

I've tried this:

```
anova(models_list)
```

but I get this:

```
Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class" c('lmList4', 'list', 'vector')"
```

So then I tried this:

```
anova.lmlist(models_list)
```

but I get an error saying it can't find this function, even though [it appears to be part of the base stats package](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/3.2.0/doc/html/Language_Reference/stats/anova.lmlist.html).

Comment: It's defined in `stats` but it's not exported. You can try `stats:::anova.lmlist(models_list)`, but beware, unexported functions are generally not meant to be called directly.

Comment: In fact, `lapply(models_list, anova)` would probably be safer.

Comment: @MrFlick I didn't know about unexported functions, thanks. My understanding of the *apply functions is still shaky but I'm not sure using `lapply` like that accomplishes what I'm after... comparing all the models to eachother (or really comparing all models to the first model)