# Writing a function that takes every row of a data frame and creates a separate data frame based on features of that row

Tags: r, function, matrix, apply

I'm looking at transitions from place to place. I will simplify my problem to make it clearer what I'm trying to do.

Suppose there are 3 places a person can go: A, B, C.

I currently have a data frame that captures transitions from place to place (it is allowed that sequential transitions can be to the same place; e.g., A to A).

```
Origin Dest Time 
     A    B  Mon
     B    C  Wed
     C    B  Fri
```

I also have created a distance matrix that captures distance from place to place.

```
   A  B  C
A  0  8 11
B  8  0  6
C 11  6  0
```

I also have a "popularity" data frame that captures how many times total any person went to A, B, C prior to some time.

```
  Popularity
B         47
C         32
A         25
```

What I'm looking to do is create a data frame (for each transition) with each row being a possible destination that the person could've went with the target variable coded 0 or 1 based on whether the person actually went to that destination. In other words, the data frame for the first transition in the above transitions data frame (A to B on Monday) should be:

```
 Origin  Dest  Went?  Dist  Time_Dest  Pop
      A     A      0     0      Mon_A   25
      A     B      1     8      Mon_B   47
      A     C      0    11      Mon_C   32
```

I want to iterate this, creating a different data frame for each transition (each row in the transitions data frame) and then append all of these data frames together to create a large data frame that will allow me to run a massive logistic regression to predict probabilities of next destination, given an origin and time.

Could someone possibly provide any insight as to how to write a function to do this? Or perhaps there is an easier way?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: You can use `split()` on your first dataframe. This will create a list of dataframes where each dataframe corresponds to one of the possible pairwise transitions. The code would look something like: `splitdf <- split(df, list(df$Origin, df$Dest))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this is can be accomplished with a few merge statements.  I'm using the `tidyverse` suite of packages to do the work, but you can very easily do this in base R.  I'll point out the changes - but the biggest will be the use of temporary variables or nesting instead of pipes.  The pipe command `%>%` is just going to call the next function in the chain with the previous result as the first argument.

```
library(tidyverse)

# generating your data
locations <- LETTERS[1:3]
n_locations <- length(locations)

# using base R, use the function expand.grid instead of crossing
location_combinations <- crossing(Origin = locations, Dest = locations)

dist_matrix <- matrix(0,nrow = n_locations, ncol = n_locations)
dist_matrix[lower.tri(dist_matrix)] <- c(8, 11, 6)
dist_matrix <- dist_matrix + t(dist_matrix)

transitions <- data_frame(
  Origin = locations,
  Dest = locations[c(2,3,2)],
  Time = c("Mon", "Wed", "Fri")
)

# Make "Dest" a vector instead of the rownames to work with it a little more easily.
popularity <- data_frame(
  Dest = locations,
  Popularity = as.integer(c(25, 47, 32))
)

# left_join can be replaced with "merge" using base R.  
# mutate can be replaced by defining/redefining each variable separately, or using the "within" command.   
tmp <- location_combinations %>%
  left_join(transitions, by = c("Origin", "Dest")) %>%
  left_join(popularity, by = "Dest") %>%
  mutate(
    Origin = as_factor(Origin),
    Dest = as_factor(Dest),
    `Went?` = !is.na(Time),
    Time_Dest = paste(Time, Dest, sep = "_"),
    index = (as.numeric(Origin)-1) * n_locations + as.numeric(Dest),
    Dist = dist_matrix[(as.numeric(Origin)-1) * length(locations) + as.numeric(Dest)]
  ) %>%
  select(-Time)
tmp
```

This gives you almost what you want.  Two differences - first, I left `Went?` as a logical vector instead of 1/0.  Multiply by 1 to fix this if needed for logistic regression.  The other difference is the "Time_Dest" column, which doesn't have a date for an event that didn't happen.  In other words, "instead of "Mon_A" for A to A, it sees "NA_A".  If this is a big problem, I can almost certainly address this with another merge/join, so let me know if you need it and can't figure it out.  (Hint - do a 2nd merge with Transitions data frame, but with  `by = origin`).

To see partial work (and better understand pipes, you can run pieces of this code.  For example, try

```
location_combinations %>%
  left_join(transitions, by = c("Origin", "Dest"))
```

Alright, so now you (more or less) have the entire data set in one spot.  To split it, there are several options.

1. You can use `split` to split it up by Origin.  The code looks like

   ```
   list_of_dfs <- split(tmp, tmp$Origin)
   ```

   This produces exactly what you asked for, a list of data frames which can be analyzed separately.
2. You can use `group_by` function in the `dplyr` package (part of `tidyverse`.)  An example using this approach is at [Linear Regression and group by in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539/linear-regression-and-group-by-in-r).  The caveat here is that the `do` function is/will be depreciated, so this isn't a solution that will work forever.  I haven't needed it recently, so I'm not sure what the "new" solution is, but this, in combination with the `broom` package can almost certainly help you to organize your results.  (See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html).

**Update to include all possible destinations**

```
location_combinations %>%
  left_join(transitions, by = c("Origin", "Dest")) %>%
  left_join(transitions %>% select(Origin, Time), by = "Origin") %>%
  left_join(popularity, by = "Dest") %>%
  mutate(
    Origin = as_factor(Origin),
    Dest = as_factor(Dest),
    `Went?` = !is.na(Time.x),
    Time_Dest = paste(Time.y, Dest, sep = "_"),
    index = (as.numeric(Origin)-1) * n_locations + as.numeric(Dest),
    Dist = dist_matrix[(as.numeric(Origin)-1) * length(locations) + as.numeric(Dest)]
  ) %>%
  select(-Time.x, -Time.y, -index)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Melissa, I'm having trouble replacing the "NA_Dest". It is important that that corresponds to the time and destination for all possible destinations the person could have went, even if he/she did not go there. I'm a bit confused how to do the second merge with the transitions df with by = "Origin". Could you explain? Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Look at the change - I've added another merge with the transition df, but ignoring destination completely.  We now have two copies of ``Time``, and the merge will label these ``Time.x`` and ``Time.y`` automatically (``Time.x`` has NAs, ``Time.y`` does not), so we just need to make sure we use the right one for ``Went?`` and ``Time_Dest``.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand now.