# Can't get aggregate() work for regression by group

Tags: r, regression, aggregate, linear-regression, lm

I want to use `aggregate` with this custom function:

```
#linear regression f-n
CalculateLinRegrDiff = function (sample){
  fit <- lm(value~ date, data = sample)
  diff(range(fit$fitted))
}

dataset2 = aggregate(value ~ id + col, dataset, CalculateLinRegrDiff(dataset))
```

I receive the error:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax on using `aggregate` is wrong in the first place. Pass function `CalculateLinRegrDiff` not an evaluated one `CalculateLinRegrDiff(dataset)` to `FUN` argument.

Secondly, you've chosen the wrong tool. `aggregate` can't help you fit a regression by group. It splits the vector on the LHS of `~` according to combinations on the RHS, and then apply `FUN` on the LHS. That is, `FUN` should be a function that works with an atomic vector not a data frame. Say, `mean`, `sd`, `quantile`, etc are all functions that take atomic vector as input. `CalculateLinRegrDiff` expects a data frame input and that is not going to work with `aggregate`.

Note that sometimes we use `cbind` on the LHS, like `cbind(x, y) ~ f`. This means that we apply `FUN` in parallel to `x ~ f` and `y ~ f`. The LHS variables are independent and not used together.

The right tool for you is the `by` function. It splits a data frame into sub data frames and applies `FUN` on each sub frame. So it is ideal for regression by group.

```
by(dataset[c("value", "date")], dataset[c("id", "col")], CalculateLinRegrDiff)
```

A simple reproducible example:

```
set.seed(0)
dataset <- data.frame(value = runif(20), date = runif(20),
                      f = sample(gl(2, 10)), g = sample(gl(4, 5)))
oo <- by(dataset[c("value", "date")], dataset[c("f", "g")], CalculateLinRegrDiff)
str(oo)
# by [1:2, 1:4] 0.307 0.251 0.109 0.201 0.472 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ f: chr [1:2] "1" "2"
#  ..$ g: chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Since `CalculateLinRegrDiff` is a scalar function that returns a single scalar, `by` will simplify the result `oo` to an array rather than a list. This array is like a contingency table, so we can use the "table" method of `as.data.frame` to reshape it to a data frame:

```
oo <- as.data.frame.table(oo)
#  f g      Freq
#1 1 1 0.3069877
#2 2 1 0.2508591
#3 1 2 0.1087895
#4 2 2 0.2007295
#5 1 3 0.4715680
#6 2 3 0.4942069
#7 1 4 0.3223174
#8 2 4 0.4687340
```

The name "Freq" may be undesired but you can easily change it. Say `names(oo)[3] <- "foo"`.

As I said in my comments under your question, we can also use `split` and `lapply`. But then there is no trivial way to convert the result into a good-looking data frame.

```
datlist <- split(dataset[c("value", "date")], dataset[c("f", "g")], drop = TRUE)
rr <- lapply(datlist, CalculateLinRegrDiff)
stack(rr)
#     values ind
#1 0.3069877 1.1
#2 0.2508591 2.1
#3 0.1087895 1.2
#4 0.2007295 2.2
#5 0.4715680 1.3
#6 0.4942069 2.3
#7 0.3223174 1.4
#8 0.4687340 2.4
```

I suggest you read [Linear Regression and group by in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169539/4891738) for a thorough demonstrations on regression by group.