# How to implement "broom" package in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, broom, rstatix, modelr

I have an issue that might be silly in some ways, but following this question:

[Linear Regression and group by in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539/linear-regression-and-group-by-in-r)

I tried to install the broom package in order to "retrieve the coefficients and Rsquared/p.value".

I know that the previous question is 12 years old but this package is still listed in my RStudio for installation, but then I have this error message and I am lost on what to do to make it work properly:

> library(broom)
> Error in value[3L]:
> Package 'broom' version 0.7.12 cannot be loaded:
> Error in unloadNamespace(package): namespace 'broom' is imported by 'modelr', 'tidyverse', 'rstatix' and therefore cannot be unloaded

So my question is straightforward: what does it mean? Did broom become a dependancy of the 3 packages cited? How to make it work?

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: screenshot of the output to know why some numbers appear in red.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried calling broom::tidy() on your model object? e.g. 
model_data <- lm(data = mtcars, formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt)
broom::tidy(model_data)

Comment: > broom::tidy(fitted_models)
Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Data frame tidiers are deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release of broom. 
2: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...):
   the argument is neither numeric nor logical: return NA

Comment: What type of object is fitted_models in this case, and what code did you use to generate it?

Comment: > class(fitted_models)
[1] "rowwise_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Comment: fitted_models = dataset %>% 
  group_by(condition) %>% 
  do(model = lm(day_number ~ time, data = .))

Comment: > fitted_models$model
[[1]]
Call:
lm(formula = day_number ~ time, data = .)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)         time  
     57.253       -5.884 //and so on for every condition so it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comments, you should be able to purrr::map broom::tidy over your list column of models.

```
fitted_models$model %>%
    purrr::map(broom::tidy)
```

This returns a list of your models with the coefficients, p-values etc. tidied.

You can also mutate a new column into your fitted_models data frame/tibble to keep your data frame/tibble data type. Note that we include model in the map() call because we are piping from fitted_models, not fitted_models$model:

```
fitted_models %>%
    mutate(tidied_models = purrr::map(model, broom::tidy)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Just one more precision, why some numbers appear in red in the results? Does it mean something (e.g. significancy)? I will edit my post and put a screenshot of the outpu to be clearer.

Comment: and maybe one last question, any way to show the Diagnostic Plots for every lm to check the assumptions?

Comment: It depends where the red is popping up, but under coefficient it means that the variable has a negative effect. You won't find red values under std.error and p.value as they can't be negative. 'Statistic' - I believe is the t statistic, which is the coefficient divided by the std.error, thus it will be negative when the coefficient is negative and it is essentially an estimate of the coefficient's variance.

Comment: Yes, you can alsp map over your models to see the diagnostic plots. I'm not sure about storing them in a column, it could be possible.

To see the plots call:

fitted_models$model %>%
    map(plot)

Comment: sorry, last error to debug: > fitted_models$model %>% map(plot)
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' / I should call purrr::map(plot) right?

Comment: I don't have access to your models/data so it's hard to say precisely what's happening. Is model still the original model objects, rather than the tidied model?
Try taking a look at fitted_models %>% unnest(model)  and then another call to fitted_models %>% unnest(tidied_models). See if you have any all NAs or similar, if you can't determine the cause, you'll need to create a new question I feel :)

Comment: these lines actually seem to work: `par(mfrow=c(2,2))
fitted_models$model %>% purrr::map(plot)` / output is all the diagnostic plots and this appears in the console for every lm:  `[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL`