# R lattice panel function fits, how can I get model summary for each panel

Tags: r, lm, lattice

How can I get a print-out of the summary for a model fit to each lattice panel?

For example, using the sleepstudy dataste from lme4:

```
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
```

I can fit a linear model to all the data and print the summary:

```
plot(sleepstudy$Days, sleepstudy$Reaction)
model <- lm(formula = Reaction ~ Days,data = sleepstudy)
abline(model, col = "salmon")
summary(model)
```

[image]
[image]

How can I do print a summary for each lattice panel?

```
xyplot(Reaction ~ Days | Subject, 
       data = sleepstudy,
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
         panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
         fm <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))
         panel.lines(x, fitted(fm), col.line="salmon")
       }
       )
```

[image]

Comment: For linear regression by group see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539/linear-regression-and-group-by-in-r#1169672

Answer (score 0):

You can get the summary functions output either as a list of the values returned or using the `print.summary`

```
lapply(split( sleepstudy, sleepstudy$ID), summary)
```

If you want the `summary.lm` result then this succeeds

```
lapply(split( sleepstudy, sleepstudy$Subject), 
   function(d) {
        summary(
           lm(Reaction ~ poly(Days, 2),data=d) )
               })
```